# Android BaseAdapter getView - any way to get real position?

Tags: android, listview

```
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
```

position here is not the actual position in ListView, as they are recycled and I need to know real position, for example if it's 24th position in ListView I need to know if it's 24.

```
  @Override
      public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
            if (view == null) { 

     view = lInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, parent, false);

              }


                imgstatus=(ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
          imgstatus.setTag(position);
          itemTap=view.findViewById(R.id.itemTap);
          itemTap.setTag(position);


//....there's a lot of stuff, but I set Tags here
}
```

So, the Issue is when I set onClick or onTouchListeners on these elements - it return me wrong tags.

For example , when I just open it and just scroll down - the tags are ok. 16 is 16, but when I scroll up and down, 16 may become 2

get the tag :

```
 itemTap.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {


                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    //skipped
    if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){
                        downtime=0L;
                        Log.d("MyLog","up. tag="+v.getTag());
                        listener_item.itemClick((Integer) v.getTag());  
                        (((RelativeLayout) v.getParent()).findViewById(R.id.ivAllother)).setBackgroundDrawable(ctx.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.spare_play));
                        return true;
                    }
}
```

so, here, `Log.d("MyLog","up. tag="+v.getTag());` returns me wrong tags after I scroll my ListView here and there

Comment: convertView is recycled not the position

Comment: how you are getting tags ?

Comment: are you sure that v is itemTap not the parentView (which is returned from getView)

Comment: there is itemTap.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() { in the code, so it's the only element with onTouchListener

Comment: I have post an answer please into it..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `getPositionForView` method as @udp said:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    int listPosition;    

    if(convertView != null) {
        listPosition = ((ListView)parent).getPositionForView(convertView);
    }

}
```

Comment: this gives me a nullPointerException

Comment: @user2976267 which object is null ?

Comment: ok, this method gives me back real number, thank you! It's strange because postiton from getView() gives me totally wrong numbers

Answer (score 1):

From the [official doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29):

```
/** 
   position The position of the item within the adapter's data set of the item whose view we want.
**/
public abstract View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

Your assumption is not true. Position is not affected by recycling. It always show the real position: the position of the item in the data set.

Answer (score 0):

```
private OnClickListener mButton = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    final int realPosition = mListView.getPositionForView((View) v.getParent());
        // do stuff
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `position` `final` and access in your `onTouch` method using

```
listener_item.itemClick(position);
```